# Getting Directions from Google Static Map for a Mobile Site

Tags: gps, driving-directions, google-maps-static-api, mobile-website

I have a mobile site I am building.  It has a Google static map on it.  I would like to be able to tie into the phone's gps and get directions through the phone.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on whether the phone's browser supports the [HTML5 Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). If it does, you can use that to grab the geolocation and plot on a Google Static Map. Most recent iPhone and Android devices support it.